# Is there an asymptotic limit for x*log(x) in relation to x^a, where a is (1,2)?

Tags: algorithm, limit, complexity-theory

I know that `O(x) < O(x*logx)` and `O(x^2)>O(x*logx)`, but what can we say about
`O(x^a) ? O(x*logx)`, where a is between 1 and 2.

Comment: **Edit:** "asymptomatic" means something completely different :-)

Comment: Try taking the logarithm of both sides and you'll see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to analyse this is to declare `y=log(x)` and rewrite our expressions:

```
1. x^a = (2^y)^a 
2. x*log(x) = (2^y)*y
```

Now take the logarithm of both:

```
1. log ((2^y)^a) = y * a
2. log ((2^y)*y) = y + log(y)
```

Subtract `y` and you get this:

```
1. y * (a-1)
2. log(y)
```

From this you can see that for all `a > 1` expression `1` grows linearly and expression 2 logarithmically, meaning that `O(x^a) > O(x*logx)` for all a > 1.